# Syntax error for function arguments in Python

Tags: python, function, arguments

I am working on homework gave out by my teacher, he wants me to write a function in Python that takes for arguments two pairs of floats, and not four floats seperated by commas. A function that should look something like this, dist_SNCF((2,1),(1,1)).

Here's my program:

```
def dist_SNCF((x1,y1),(x2,y2)):
    if abs(x1 * y2 -y1 * x2) <= 10**(-10):
        return dist_eucl(x1-x2,y1-y2)
    else:
        return dist(x1,y1)+dist(x2,y2)
```

However, it seems like I can't simply do it like this. As it is marked syntax error for the function's arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You may be working with older material. This was a valid syntax in Python 2.7, but it was removed in Python 3.0. See [*PEP 3113 – Removal of Tuple Parameter Unpacking*](https://peps.python.org/pep-3113/).

Workaround for Python 2/3 cross-compatible code:

```
def dist_SNCF(tup1, tup2):
    (x1, y1), (x2, y2) = tup1, tup2
    ...
```